Linear Regression R-Squared Adjusted
i have some problems with formulas.
The first formula that i found in the internet
$R^2_{Adjusted} = 1 - (1 - R^2)(\frac{n-1}{n-k})$
The second formula
$R^2_{Adjusted} = 1 - (1 - R^2)[\frac{n-1}{n-(k+1)}]$
I calculate R-Squared Adjusted through stats.model in Python and thats it equal 0.610408.
R-Squared ≈ 0.6415759298804311
n = 51
k = 4
First formula result = 1 - (1 - 0.64157) * (50 / 47) ≈ 0.61869
Second formula result = 1 - (1 - 0.64157) * (50 / 46) ≈ 0.610408
Why is the first formula that is on the internet incorrect?

Both are correct. It just depends on what $k$ is. The first forumla includes the intercept in $k$, the second one does not. You can get the $k$ for your model by ncol(model.matrix(your_lm_object)) in R.

So both formulas correct, but k + 1 include intercept also? But why, i think rule for R-Adjusted is should not include intercept.

If your model is $$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \cdots + \beta_kx_k + u$$ then you have to use $k+1$. If your model is $$y  = \beta_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \cdots + \beta_kx_k +u$$ then you have to use just $k$. Why do you think the formula should not include the intercept?
